# `wget` is not recognized or either can't find the file

Tags: wget

if i use

`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin`

then i'm able to use wget commands

for example:

`wget http://www.ultralightnews.com/trikes/images/trikes/dfs-singletrike.jpg`

but i can't find the file back, i looked in c:\ and in the bin folder mentioned above and in GnuWin32\etc

If i try

`wget -O C:\Users\clankill3r\Downloads\wgetfolder wget http://www.ultralightnews.com/trikes/images/trikes/dfs-singletrike.jpg`

then it says `Permision denied`, i did allow all permisions possible for every group / user.

Some people say it downloads to the current folder your working in (that's why i looked in the bin). But i thought let's try to run the command from another folder so i used:

'cd C:\Users\clankill3r\Downloads\wgetfolder`and then the wget comman but then it says the`wget` command is not recognized.

can someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin` then your current directory is just that. **If it is allowed to write in that place** it will write the file to that place. However I really hope that is is not allowed to write in program files.

(Still, that should not cause a silent failure. It really should give an error).

`cd C:\Users\clankill3r\Downloads\wgetfolder` makes the wgetfolder your current folder. If you do it that way document will end up there.

---

So much for the locations where your downloaded files should end up.

The *command not recognised* is an other issue. When you type a command windows looks for hat command in a few places. One of them is the current directory. The others are specified in %PATH%.

You probably did not add C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\ to the path. (you can check this but typing `path` in a cmd window). On your first try you accidently started to command from the directory in which it was stored, and thus did not run into this problem.

To solve that, either specify the full path to the program, or add it to %path%

Full example:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe http://www.ultralightnews.com/trikes/images/trikes/dfs-singletrike.jpg`

Path adding: (via GUI)

- [My computer], right click
- properties
- Advanced system settings
- Environment variables.
- [Edit] (either per user, or system wide)

[image]

Comment: thanks, i will try when i'm home.
For path adding, how must i name the variable? And i have to locate to the bin folder right?

Comment: You do not need to name a new variable. Use the existing one named *path*. Select it, click edit. It will show a number of search paths seperated by a `;`. Append `;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\ ` to that.